# Load and disappear

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a button inside a background:

```
<div id="background">
<div id="button">button</div>  
</div>
```

With jQuery I load the div of another page.

```
$(function(){      
    $("#button").click(function() {
        $("#background").load("document.html #note");
    });  
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9Sn9e/

The div loaded is much smaller than the background and it is positioned in the center:

```
#note{
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 150px;
    width:200px;
    height: 200px;
    line-height:200px;
    background-color: #eee;
}
```

I can load it, but when it is loaded the button disappear. Why?

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't include the `<div id="fons"></div>` element. If your button is contained within the `fons` div, that would explain why it's disappearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ids are completely different in the html and the javascript.
If the ids match, as you are loading the content into the div, the content of the div is completely replace and not appended to the existing content.

Modify your html as -

```
<div id="background">
    <div id="fons"></div> 
    <div id="boto">button</div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry the names of the divs were wrong. Now I correct them. The question is: if I load something in a div anything that were in that div will disappear and there is no way to make it visible?

Comment: Nope. If you load the div content would be replaced. You would need to use the structure as in the example, to prevent losing elements.